Crashlytics notification that crash report sending is finished
Is there a way to know when Crashlytics has finished sending report? There is a method sendUnsentReports, which can be used together with checkAndUpdateUnsentReportsWithCompletion method, but it just "Enqueues any unsent reports on the device to upload to Crashlytics", but how do I know when upload is finished?
